# How to Subtract the first element in a vector from another first element in another vector?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have 2 vectors of ints.

say the first one has (2,1).
and the second one (1,1).

I am trying to subtract numbers like this:

2 - 1,
1 - 1

then I need to add these 2 numbers so the final answer would be 1.

I've tried a for loop, but it's subtracting each number from each element, instead of only the first one.

This is what I've tried so far.

```
vector<int> temp;

for(unsigned i =0; i < Vec1.size(); i++)
 for(unsigned o =0; o < Vec2.size(); o++)
   temp.push_back(Vec1.at(i).nums- Vec2.at(o).nums);

//where nums, are just the numbers showed above
```

The output as you would expect is : 
1

1

0

0

and I need it to be:

1

0

then I can just do a for loop to add all the ints together.

Any help, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: idt you need another data structure here, you can do this in one go like `result += Vec1.at(i).nums- Vec2.at(o).nums`

Comment: @roottraveller That would output 2, it should be just 1, my problem here is that each element is being subtracted from every other element in Vec2, and I only want it to subtract the first element from Vec2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've tried a for loop, but it's subtracting each number from each element, instead of only the first one.

You are not doing it the right way. You have been using `cascaded` for loops and hence, you are subtracting each element of first `vector` from each element of second `vector`.

There are two ways to correctly implement:

One involves writing your own functions to subtract two `vector` and then adding elements of the result.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


std::vector<int> subtract(const std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& b)
{
    std::vector<int> result;
    const int SIZE = std::min(a.size(), b.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        result.push_back(a[i] - b[i]);

    return result;
}


int addAllElements(const std::vector<int>& a)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (auto i: a)
        result += i;
    return result;
}


int main(void)
{
    std::vector<int> a = {2, 1};
    std::vector<int> b = {1, 1};

    std::cout << "Result is " << addAllElements(subtract(a, b)) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The other method (preferred) involves using `STL`:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

int main(void) 
{
    std::vector<int> a = { 2, 1 };
    std::vector<int> b = { 1, 1 };

    std::vector<int> result;
    std::transform(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(b), std::back_inserter(result), [](const auto a, const auto b) 
        {
            return a - b;
        } 
    );

    int sumAllElements = std::accumulate(result.begin(), result.end(), 0);
    std::cout << "Result is " << sumAllElements << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The above code uses `lambda expression`. To know more about them, see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11).

`std::accumulate` sums all the elements of the `container` and `std::transform` performs the transformation (specified in it's fifth argument) on two vectors and put the result in a different vector. We have used `lambda expression` to perform the required `sub` operation.

**EDIT:**

To implement it without `lambda` is also easy. You can use `function pointers`.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

double subtract(const double a, const double b)
{
    return a - b;
}

int main(void) 
{
    std::vector<int> a = { 2, 1 };
    std::vector<int> b = { 1, 1 };

    std::vector<int> result;
    std::transform(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(b), std::back_inserter(result), subtract);

    int sumAllElements = std::accumulate(result.begin(), result.end(), 0);
    std::cout << "Result is " << sumAllElements << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

There are various advantages of using lambda expression.

**NOTE:**

You can also use `std::minus` instead of defining you own function. Like this:

```
std::transform(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(b), std::back_inserter(result), std::minus<int>());
```

Comment: Pleasure is mine. See my edited answer. It points out the mistake in your code!

Comment: how would you do that without that Lambda expression please?

Comment: There is [`std::minus`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/minus)(C++14) instead of `substract`

Answer (score 3):

In C++17, you can combine `std::transform` and `std::reduce`/`std::accumulate` calls with [`std::transform_reduce`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform_reduce):

```
const std::vector<int> vec1 {2, 1};
const std::vector<int> vec2 {1, 1};
auto res = std::transform_reduce(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(),
                                 vec2.begin(),
                                 0,
                                 std::plus<>(),
                                 std::minus<>());
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5AJ5Kg)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using the STL:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec1 {2, 1};
    std::vector<int> vec2 {1, 1};
    std::vector<int> temp;
    std::transform(begin(vec1), std::end(vec1), std::begin(vec2),
        std::back_inserter(temp), [](const auto a, const auto b) {return a - b;});
    auto sum = std::accumulate(temp.begin(), temp.end(), 0);
    std::cout << "Result: " << sum << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That works, could you please, please explain your code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Hugs You are welcome, what would you like to know about the code?

Comment: this particular part please [](const auto a, const auto b) {return a - b;});

Comment: This is called an anonymous lambda function, see [Lambda expression in C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lambda-expression-in-c/) for an introduction

Comment: Last Question I promise, How would you do this without that Lambda function please?

Comment: lambda can be replaced by standard `std::minus<>{}` or regular custom functor.